Want to refer to "current row and cell" from another worksheet
I've got a workbook with a worksheet per month. Each month has the same overall format, i.e., I type numbers into the same cells on each worksheet and have the same formulas in the other non-empty cells. There is often text to help me keep track of what they mean.
I like to have the text from the Jan worksheet appear in the same cells in the other monthly worksheets. So far I've been putting a different formula in each cell for this, e.g., "=Jan!B15" in the B15 cell for Feb, Mar, Apr, etc. There are probably 20-30 such cells on each month after Jan. I find this useful if I improve the text, so I only have to change it in one place. There have been no cases for these worksheets where I would want the text to be different; if I run into one, I will change the text on the worksheet that needs to be different, and would still use this for most of them.
The "Jan!B15" method works, but I wondered if there were a way to refer to the current cell row and column without it having to be explicit. I'm looking for something like "=Jan!thisCell", and then copy that into every cell where I want the January text value on the current worksheet.
I've read that, if I change the spreadsheet to "RC" format addressing, I could use "=Jan!RC", where "RC" in a formula refers to the current cell. But I do not want to switch these worksheets over to RC format addressing. I'm too used to the other one, which is used on these worksheets in other places. So I'm afraid changing to that addressing style is not a good solution for me.
I read about creating a named range called "THIS_CELL" and using it, but the only examples they have are as parameters to functions, and "=Jan!THIS_CELL" did not do what I wanted. I don't understand the named ranges fully, so perhaps there's something there that would work.
I'd welcome suggestions.

You may try INDIRECT() like-
=INDIRECT("Jan!"&ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()))

